# I'm trying to use Prophet from fbprophet but I'm getting this excuciatingly long error message no idea what's suppose to mean?

Tags: streamlit

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/r4/nqsj60p57yq9vh_zy4fq6n000000gn/T/pip-install-91n1df76/fbprophet_e94a6b9aeb83455cb3e0fdf4115391fb/setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'/private/var/folders/r4/nqsj60p57yq9vh_zy4fq6n000000gn/T/pip-install-91n1df76/fbprophet_e94a6b9aeb83455cb3e0fdf4115391fb/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/r4/nqsj60p57yq9vh_zy4fq6n000000gn/T/pip-record-2j0pe0nh/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/fbprophet
cwd: /private/var/folders/r4/nqsj60p57yq9vh_zy4fq6n000000gn/T/pip-install-91n1df76/fbprophet_e94a6b9aeb83455cb3e0fdf4115391fb/
Complete output (40 lines):
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib
creating build/lib/fbprophet
creating build/lib/fbprophet/stan_model
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "/private/var/folders/r4/nqsj60p57yq9vh_zy4fq6n000000gn/T/pip-install-91n1df76/fbprophet_e94a6b9aeb83455cb3e0fdf4115391fb/setup.py", line 122, in 
setup(
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/**init**.py", line 165, in setup
return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
dist.run_commands()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
self.run_command(cmd)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 61, in run
return orig.install.run(self)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/command/install.py", line 546, in run
self.run_command('build')
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
self.distribution.run_command(command)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
self.run_command(cmd_name)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
self.distribution.run_command(command)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
File "/private/var/folders/r4/nqsj60p57yq9vh_zy4fq6n000000gn/T/pip-install-91n1df76/fbprophet_e94a6b9aeb83455cb3e0fdf4115391fb/setup.py", line 48, in run
build_models(target_dir)
File "/private/var/folders/r4/nqsj60p57yq9vh_zy4fq6n000000gn/T/pip-install-91n1df76/fbprophet_e94a6b9aeb83455cb3e0fdf4115391fb/setup.py", line 38, in build_models
StanBackendEnum.get_backend_class(backend).build_model(target_dir, MODEL_DIR)
File "/private/var/folders/r4/nqsj60p57yq9vh_zy4fq6n000000gn/T/pip-install-91n1df76/fbprophet_e94a6b9aeb83455cb3e0fdf4115391fb/fbprophet/models.py", line 209, in build_model
import pystan
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pystan'
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/r4/nqsj60p57yq9vh_zy4fq6n000000gn/T/pip-install-91n1df76/fbprophet_e94a6b9aeb83455cb3e0fdf4115391fb/setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'/private/var/folders/r4/nqsj60p57yq9vh_zy4fq6n000000gn/T/pip-install-91n1df76/fbprophet_e94a6b9aeb83455cb3e0fdf4115391fb/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/r4/nqsj60p57yq9vh_zy4fq6n000000gn/T/pip-record-2j0pe0nh/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/fbprophet Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide more info on when does the error occur.

Answer (score 10):

> /fbprophet/models.py", line 209, in build_model import pystan **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pystan'** ---------------------------------------- ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1

This is your error message. Have you installed pystan ?

If you have and are still getting this error then try uninstalling pystan and install a older version.

I had the same issue and the below worked for me:

**Step 1: Uninstall pystan**

```
pip uninstall pystan
```

**Step 2: Install pystan version ~2.14**

```
pip install pystan~=2.14
```

**Step 3: Try installing fbprophet again **

```
pip install fbprophet
```

[Reference](https://github.com/facebook/prophet/issues/17).

Comment: Thank u very much for your help I managed to uninstall pystan 3.0.0 but couldn't install pystan 2.14 just got even more gibberish and this time all in red. But ur help is greatly appreciated Thanks

Comment: No worries, I too struggled for a while before finding the above solution to work for me. Do feel free to share the error messages ,even I had got a few red ones :) . I am sure someone here would be able to help with those. Also check out the reference I shared above, its from the fbprophet github issue page, you may find a solution there.

Comment: Thank you, I got same error. The given solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

After making sure you have the right python version.
Update apt and install following libraries.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3-dev python3-pip python3-venv
```

use python3 -m pip to install pystan and prophet

```
python3 -m pip pystan 
python3 -m pip prophet
```